# How to make SSIS truncate numeric field in Flat File Destination

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I'd like some advice about handling truncation issues in SSIS. I have a column Col1 which is `MONEY` in a table. I'd like to output that to a text file (fixed width, ragged right). In the output file, the column which holds Col1 must only be 8 characters wide.

In the OLEDB Data Source, Col1 is specified as:
`currency [DT_CY]` in both the External Columns and Output Columns tab.

In the Flat File Connection Manager's Advanced tab, Col1 is specified as:
`currency [DT_CY]`, with `InputColumnWidth` set to 8.

If I populate Col1 with 123456789.00 and execute the task, the OLEDB source succeeds and passes rows to the destination, but the task fails with :

> Error: 0xC02020A1 at DFT_Test, FFDEST_Test [3955]: Data conversion
>   failed. The data conversion for column "Col1" returned status value 4
>   and status text "Text was truncated or one or more characters had no
>   match in the target code page.". 
> Error: 0xC02020A0 at DFT_Test,
>   FFDEST_Test [3955]: Cannot copy or convert flat file data for column
>   "Col1".

I want to avoid these truncation errors. In the Error Output of the source, I change the Truncation property for Col1 from Fail Component to Ignore Failure. I would have expected that would resolve the issue, but executing the task still gives the same error.

Can someone give some guidance about how to make SSIS simply truncate the column to 8 charactes?

Answer (score 1):

Use a `Derived Column` task to create a column that is an 8-character string and populate it from the `money` column.   Then in the Destination component, map the `Derived Column` to the Col1 Destination instead of the original column.

Or, even better, in your source component, use a SQL query that converts your money column to a varchar(8) or char(8) column.

Comment: I realise that it is possible to achieve this via T-SQL in the source component, but what I was after was how to configure the components in SSIS to do this. In DTS, the Copy Column Transform truncates by default.

Comment: In SSIS we have the Derived Column or the Data Conversion transforms.

Comment: I realise that I can use the Data Conversion transforms in SSIS to convert the money value to a string, then take the leftmost 8 characters. But there are dozens of fields. To do this for each one requires a **lot** of time clicking and entering formulas manually. In T-SQL, I can get a list of column name into Excel, create a formula, and obtain within **seconds** the SELECT statement I need to do the conversion. I think this is yet another case of "do it in T-SQL because in SSIS it is messy/time-consuming/error-prone/impossible."!

Comment: Well if you want to learn BiML, you can probably simulate what excel can do using only SSIS.

Comment: That's a good suggestion. I've Googled it and it looks promising.